# Precisa ficar usando o android studio para programar em react native

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native

É preciso do android studio para programar em react native?
Minha maquina não roda bem o programa, mal dá para usa-lo na verdade.
Enquanto ao emulador eu posso testas os apps pelo celular sem problemas.
Já me falaram que só preciso criar um projeto no android studio e depois pode programar em outra ide. E daria para fazer isso em uma versão mais antiga do android studio?
E só por curiosidade, o mesmo vale para programar em java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode programar em react-native em qualquer IDE, o Android Studio lhe fornece o emulador, mas você pode baixar um emulador separado, exemplo [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) e desenvolver em outro editor...

Caso você queira usar a [expo](https://expo.io/) para facilitar o desenvolvimento com react-native, você poderá usar um emulador fornecido por eles na [web](https://snack.expo.io/), tanto para Android quanto para IOS.

Você também poderá emular diretamente no seu celular, usando o [App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=en_US) da expo e escaneando o Qr code.

Caso não use a expo você poderá emular o App no seu celular também, via usb.

Comment: Por acaso você conhece outra opção de emulador além do Genymotion que seja gratuita?

Comment: @ViniciusGabriel, Não conheço nenhum gratuito além do que vem integrado ao Android Studio, mas para mim a maneira mais eficaz de testar o app em react-native é usar o próprio aparelho, ou usar o editor/emulador fornecido pela expo.

Comment: Você acha que usar o expo é uma melhor opção? Dizem que ele é muito limitado.

Comment: @CélioJúnior, tudo depende do seu projeto, você deve levantar todos os requisitos e consultar a documentação da expo para verificar se atende sua demanda, se sim, eu recomendo usá-la pois o desenvolvimento fica muito mais simples e rápido, além disso hoje em dia a expo está muito avançada, tudo que eu precisei no meu aplicativo eu achei lá, até suporte offline, mas, se você precisa de um build final pequeno, a expo gera os aplicativos com no mínimo 19 mb para Android e 40 mb para IOS, independente da quantidade de código, isso pode ser um problema em alguns casos.